# How to measure quality of image before compressing

Tags: c#, image-processing

I am using C#.

I have a jpeg image.

I compress it by reducing the quality of the image lie so:

```
byte[] data = SaveJpeg(myJPEG, 60);

public byte[] SaveJpeg(Image img, int quality)
{
    byte[] data = null;
    // Encoder parameter for image quality 
    EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);
    // Jpeg image codec 
    ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
    EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
    encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        img.Save(ms, jpegCodec, encoderParams);
        data = ms.ToArray();
        img.Dispose();
    }
    return data;
  }

  private ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(string mimeType)
  {
      // Get image codecs for all image formats 
      ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();

      // Find the correct image codec 
      for (int i = 0; i < codecs.Length; i++)
         if (codecs[i].MimeType == mimeType)
             return codecs[i];
      return null;
    }
```

my image is reduced in size as expected.

This particular image 'looks' of high quality and the compression returns 20818 in bytes. But for other images of the same resolution (ie width + height) but 'looks' a poorer image the returned byte size is a lot less - like 9000 bytes (for example).

Hoe can I get a consistent process that will return 'roughly' the same amount of bytes? What are the factors within an image that affects the size of the compression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, "quality" is a meaningless term in JPEG. Various encoders us a quality value a simplified means for specifying the quantization tables used in compression.

The effect of quantization tables depends upon the image itself. There is no way to have a specific setting that will give files about the same size with reasonable output in JPEG.

Second, the factors that effect compression outside the image are:

1. The nature of the image itself.
2. The sampling used. It is common to use fewer samples of the Cr and Cr components than the Y component. If you take 1 Cb and 1 Cr value for a rectangle of 4 Y values, you have already reduced the amount of data by half.
3. The quantization tables used.

Third, if you then go inside the image, that means the images, divided int 8x8 blocks, produces high order DCT values close to zero compress better. I know that is kind of meaningless unless you know the insides of JPEG.

Some visible factors:

Large solid areas compress well. An 8x8 block all of one color produces an 8x8 set of DCT values that are all zero, except one. In addition, subsampling Cb and Cb in such areas has no negative affect on the output.

Clean transitions do not compress well while producing good output.

Dramatic, back and forth changes in color at the pixel level does not compress well.

Comment: all very interesting stuff! I will look into applying 'take 1 Cb and 1 Cr value per 4 y. Would the best approach be to use an average filter on those 4 Cr and 4 Cb's?

Comment: That's the normal way. You should check your file format standard to determine what subsampling is supported. The JPEG standard allows anything (e.g. 3:2 sampling) but the implemented file formats do not.

Comment: Hi again. I loaded an image into emgu. I use the color space of ycc. I enumerate through the image using the data array exposed by the emgu image class. I 'flatten/average' values of Cb + Cr. The resultant image looks the same but some of the diversity of the colors is lessened (which is expected). The byte size is identical to the original. I have tried sampling with x4, x8 and x16. The byte array size is always the same. Am I doing this correctly or..? Appreciate any further comments you may have :) thanks

Comment: Are you doing the sampling yourself or using the library? Does your library support it? Page 4 here talks about sampling in JFIF. This is more clear in that the averaging should take into account the surrounding pixels as well to lessen block effects.

Comment: Hi, there was no link in your comment for me to read :(.  Yes I was doing the sampling myself.  When I checked the pixel values after sampling then going by a 2x2 block of pixels the cb and cr have been averaged out whilst the y components remain the same. I can just about discern the differences in the colors of the image after processing. Thanks for taking time to reply to me..

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a bit more involved than just the resolution and file size of the original image. What is in the image affects how much it can be compressed; so you can't really do this.

But there's more, even. Previous/existing compression is actually irrelevant. JPEG is a 'lossy' format... so there is no decompression involved. Something odd: Save an image at the max quality (lowest compression), and you'll often get a *larger* file size than originally. Often, much larger.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment and observation.  I had suspected it was what arrangement was in the image that affected compression. My only objective is to upload an image to my web server as small as possible in bytes without losing too much quality.  I just cannot seem to find a way to do this...